# fluttrer Firebase authStateChanges doesn't get triggered

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Updated my MacBook Pro M1 to Big Sur **11.3**, iOS simulator was updated to **14.5**

Now my Flutter project, which is using Firebase auth and used to work just fine, is showing chaotic authentication behaviour, both on simulator and iOS device (both iOS 14.5):

1. I login as UserA, authStateChanges doesn't trigger
2. I login as UserB, authStateChanges gets triggered - everything works just fine
3. I restart the app (VSCode) and I find myself back in the login screen, since authStateChanges returns null (firebaseUser = null, see code)

Tested **firebase_auth: ^1.0.0** and **firebase_auth: ^1.1.2**

Sample code (used to work just fine):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User firebaseUser) {
// if null goto login screen, otherwise goto user screen
});
```

Downloading iOS 14.4 Simulator - in order to test my app on it...

UPDATE:
So I see the same behavior with iOS 14.4 Simulator.
Is it possible that something has changed with my Firebase auth settings?
What can cause this?

UPDATE 2:
Tested on my iPhone, in release mode, and I see the same behavior:
After killing my app, I find myself back in the login screen...
So it's obviously a new compiled version that causes this, but I have no idea what it is...

UPDATE 3:
Just reverted to a 2 weeks old version of my code, still the same issue!
So I'm starting to think that's not a code issue, but rather a Mac configuration issue - maybe **Big Sur 11.3**, maybe the new Flutter version (**2.0.5**)
Very frustrating...

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, it's a problem in the 1.1.2 version. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5952

Comment: Still now working to me... Changed to versions 1.0.4 (core) and 1.1.1 (auth), did all the cleanup, and ever erased all content from simulator. Still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is already an open issue for that: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5952

If I use old versions, it works for me:

```
firebase_core: 1.0.4
firebase_auth: 1.1.1
```

Then you have to do:

```
flutter clean 
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
flutter run
```

Comment: Still now working to me...
Changed to versions 1.0.4 (core) and 1.1.1 (auth), did all the cleanup, and ever erased all content from simulator. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Could you check in your Pubspec.lock that your versions are the same that in your pubspec.yaml? Could you check in your Podfile.lock that your version is:  Firebase/Auth (7.3.0)?

Comment: Oh my god! That was it!
I was using the carrot notation:
firebase_core: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth: ^1.0.0

I now understand that it took the latest versions (visible in pubspec.lock)

Updated it to:
firebase_core: 1.0.4
firebase_auth: 1.1.1

And it works!
Thanks so much!

Where can I further read on thepub spec.yaml syntax rules?